# In Ruby, change global in thread safe block

Tags: ruby, globals

In Ruby, I have a use case for a few common configuration options, e.g. NOOP, TRACE, SILENT. Right now I am using local vars instead of globals and passing them around all over the place and it's a pain. I be perfectly happy to use globals for these, if I could run a block where the globals can be temporarily changed and then reverted back. e.g.

```
 global_configure(:TRACE=>true) do
   ...
 end
```

But how can I make that block of code thread safe, so that other threads can't change the globals on it?

Comment: If something is global and mutable, it can be changed from anywhere at any time, and therefore is not threadsafe, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is: don't do that.

You aren't giving away a lot about your specifics, but one key question is: why are there other threads?

If the other threads are concurrent requests that happen to share the code and some global data, they you really don't want to arbitrarily turn on tracing for an entirely different request.

If the other threads are part of the current request (say background processing) then you want to ensure consistency, so  you should be setting the global state at a point where you control the thread state, preferably when the other threads are inactive.

In general, this kind of problem is better solved with a configuration class that you inject into the request/thread as you start it, so each has its own.

With more details about your environment a better answer might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure has a solution with dynamic variables and the `binding` form, which allows you to set a global variable to a value only for the execution of a code block, without affecting other threads that might use that variable.

Ruby doesn't have that feature built-in, but I've found a gem that implements something similar: http://cirw.in/blog/lspace. You use it like this:

```
LSpace.with(:TRACE=>true) do
    # ... code code code
    puts LSpace[:TRACE]
    # ... code code code
end
```

One key difference between the Clojure implementation and the Ruby gem to keep in mind is that in the Clojure version if you spawn a new thread from inside the block where the variable is bound, the new thread will get the bounded value, and in the Ruby version it wouldn't - so if you have to depend on that functionality you better pass those configuration options as arguments (or as member fields).